# Play Audio Streaming with Android

Tags: android, audio, streaming

Require develop streaming audio playback with mediaplayer on android.
Any ideas ?!
Thanks

I try the following code:

```
 play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = "http://stream.radiosai.net:8002/"; // your URL here

            MP.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            try {
                MP.setDataSource(url);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            MP.prepareAsync(); 
            MP.start();

        }           
    });
```

The above does not work Error deploying

Answer (score 1):

```
MP.start();
```

Should be called after the mediaplager is ready, in `setOnPreparedListener`.

When you create MediaPlayer object, add prepared listener

```
MP.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: The steam is valud? Works ? Do you get any exception message?

Comment: the streaming works, but is loading forever  without message exception

Comment: Maybe Android don't support the stream? http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: In the project of @cdonner is reproducing without problem

Answer (score 0):

The German computer magazine C't recently published an article with the source code for an Android alarm clock radio. You can download the project files [here](ftp://ftp.heise.de/pub/ct/listings/1404-182.zip). I think this contains everything that you need.